# Is this a new way to extend an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

While upgrading a private yeoman generator I stumpled upon [this statement](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/42c2c6f4e4a5237563591a93dc5e64ec8c3a2699/app/index.js#L88) while looking through the official [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp):

```
const { features } = answers;
```

I wasn't able to find anything about this, aside from the fact that it only works on [node >=6](https://travis-ci.org/yeoman/generator-webapp/builds/236343518).

What does this statement do? Where is this defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [*destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's equivalent to:

```
const features = answers.features;
```

It was introduced in ES2015.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will accept as soon as the timeout has passed… ;-)

Comment: @nietonfir: No worries. BTW, no idea what I was thinking, object destructuring was in ES2015 along with array destructuring. (Brain a bit fuzzy today.) *(Edit: Ah, I know what I was thinking of: [Spread and rest properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which unlike spread and rest for arrays, are still just a proposal.)*

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const { features } = answers;
```

Is the shorthand of this:

```
const features = answers.features;
```

You could also declare many variables in a single line, see following please:

```js
var answers = {"features": "test"};
const { features } = answers;
console.log(features);

var longObj = {"attr1": "val1", "attr2" : "val2"};
const { attr1, attr2 } = longObj;
console.log(attr1, attr2);
```

I hope it was clear. Bye.